# Get other value based on active cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheets / Google app's script

I'm want to know how to get a Cell, based in my current active Cell. Example:

A table where my active Cell is at G15, im wanna get the value of C15 (same row, but C column) and the value of C3 (same column now). To get the logic, imagines if my current Cell change to (example) H7, so, i would get C7 and H3.

I know It maybe is very simple, but im learning, so, im don't very very good ate that.

Comment: What do you mean by '_value C15 **and** value C3_'? Should it be two values with coma in between ('abc','def')? Or with spaces ('abc' 'def')? Or should it be concatenated strings ('abcdef')? Or sum of the two numbers? Or, why not?, did you mean a boolean AND operator (&&)?

Comment: So, did you get an answer after all? It's not exactly a good thing to ask questions, get answers, and disappear without any feedback. To say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into the cell G15 this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, $C15, G$3)
```

And then copy it from G15 to H7, etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can also achieve this using Apps Script:

```
function returnVals() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  let row = activeCell.getRow();
  let col = activeCell.getColumn();
  let colCValue = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
  let sameCol = sheet.getRange(3,col).getValue();
  console.log(colCValue);
  console.log(sameCol);
}
```

The `getActiveCell` method will return the active cell from the sheet and the `getRow` and `getColumn` will get the `row` and the `col` of the active cell. Afterwards, based on the `row` and `col` retrieved, the function above will simply get the values you need by using the `getRange` and `getValue` methods.

So if the **active cell** is `G17`, the `row` will be `17` and the `col` will be `7`; therefore:

- `colCValue` will be the value corresponding to the (`17`,`3`) range which is `C17`;
- `sameCol` will be the value corresponding to the (`3`, `7`) range which is `G3`.

#### Reference

- [getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell());
- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getRow());
- [getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getColumn());
- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column);
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValue()).